# Is my solution to readers-writers valid?

Tags: concurrency

Global variables are: semaphore `writers` with initial value `1`, lock `lock`, and integer `count` with initial value `0`.

Here is the algorithm for writing:

```
writers.down()
...
writers.up()
```

And for reading:

```
lock.acquire()
if count++ == 0:
    writers.down()
lock.release()
...
lock.acquire()
if --count == 0:
    writers.up()
lock.release()
```

I believe that is correct. But how should I prove this rigorously?